# SVG foreignObject and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a problem with absolute and relative positioning when I use it on html objects inside a `svg:foreignObject`.

I have made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FS654/1/) to demonstrate my problem.

The `div.wrapper` should be at the same position as the `rect` in the `svg:g`, and the paragraphs inside this div should be positioned as described in the css.

I have the problem in the following browsers (Mac):

- Safari 6.0.3
- Chrome 26.0.1410.63
- Maxthon 4.0.3.6000.

It works as I expect in Firefox 19.0.2.

Is there a problem with my code? Do anyone know how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I found [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23113), which might be the problem. It looks like there are a lot of issues with `foreignObject` on the [issue tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=foreignobject) for webkit.

If someone have a workaround of how to position the paragraphs in the corners of the div I would appreciate it.

Comment: It works for me if I specify the units in the `transform` in the SVG, i.e. `translate(50px,50px)`.

Comment: That just moves the `g` to (0,0) because `translate(50px,50px)` is invalid. See section 7.4 here: [SVG Coordinate system transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html)

Comment: workaround could be to set the x="50" and y="50" for the foreignobject. <foreignObject width="200px" height="200px" x="50" y="50">

Comment: wow this bug is a decade old :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Long time since this post and the bug persist.

I actually found out that if you use `x="50" Y="50"` attributes in your `foreignObject` element it works as expected in Chrome.

I know it is not the same as `transform`, but at least you can position your content properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
<foreignObject width="200px" height="200px">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wrapper" style="position: fixed">
        <p id="topleft">topleft</p>
        <p id="topright">topright</p>
        <p id="middle">middle</p>
        <p id="bottomleft">bottomleft</p>
        <p id="bottomright">bottomright</p>
    </div>
   </foreignObject>
```

**position: fixed**