# Creating an image map using Javascript, not an SVG (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, responsive

I'm trying to create a map of button elements that overlay a full-screen image, positioned over all the 'buttons' depicted on the image. When the image resizes, the button elements should resize as well.

I initially used an SVG image map for this, but it had a positioning bug (the link below) that didn't allow for the video player inside the  `foreignObject` to show.

[SVG foreignObject and absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040631/svg-foreignobject-and-absolute-positioning)

I figured using absolute positioning, and JS to measure the width of the background image was the best way to go. However, I'm having trouble making it work.

Below is the project, with the white box needing to be positioned over the background image (the entire box, with chocolates, and the screen).

[image: desktop with full size image and div]

The image is within a div as a background, like so:

```
export const BackgroundLightsOn = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  background: url(${BgLightsOn});
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
`
```

Unfortunately, getting the dimensions of this DOM element gets the dimensions of the div, not the image (which is sometimes larger than the viewport). Below is the 'resizing' code, but this connects to backgroundRef (which is the div element the image is the background, not the image itself).

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  TruffleTinContainer,
  TruffleTinOutside,
} from '../truffle-tin/styledTruffleTin';

export default function TruffleTin({ backgroundRef }) {
  const truffleTinRef = useRef();
  const initialPos = { x: 150, y: 150 };
  const padding = 25;
  let truffleBoxWidth = 0;
  let truffleBoxHeight = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    truffleBoxWidth = truffleTinRef.current.offsetWidth;
    truffleBoxHeight = truffleTinRef.current.offsetHeight;
    resize();
  }, []);

  function resize() {
    let backgroundDivRect = backgroundRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    truffleTinRef.current.style.left =
      (initialPos.x / truffleBoxWidth) * backgroundDivRect.width -
      padding +
      'px';
    truffleTinRef.current.style.top =
      (initialPos.y / truffleBoxHeight) * backgroundDivRect.height -
      padding +
      'px';
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
  });

  return (
    <TruffleTinContainer ref={truffleTinRef}>
      I'm the truffle tin
    </TruffleTinContainer>
  );
}
```

See the GIF below for the issue:

[image]

What's the best way to get this div to proportionally match the width of the background image?

(Edit: I changed the 'div with image background' to an `img` tag, but even then, the `getBoundingClientRect` shows not the width of the image, but the width of the viewport:

[image]

**(in other words, even though the image is much wider than the viewport, I'm still getting the viewports dimensions, when what I want is the image's dimensions))**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS for that. This is achieved with plain CSS, all you need is the button center positions relative to left-top corner of the block. Sample HTML/CSS:

```
<div class='wrapper'> <!-- Will need this later -->
    <div class='container'>
        <a class='button' style='--left: 25%; --top: 20%'>1</a>
        <a class='button' style='--left: 35%; --top: 80%'>2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    background: url('/path/to/image');
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
.button{
    position: absolute;
    left: var(--left);
    top: var(--top);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Move button a bit so its center matches the actual position */

    /* These are just for visualization */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: pink;
    display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;

}
```

The next step is to make `.container` have a constant width, or at least a constant width/height ratio if you care about vertical resizing. The constant width is achieved with a simple `min-width`. To avoid horizontal scroll we will add a `.wrapper` to hide the cut-off sides:

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* A-and a min-width for .container */
.container{
    min-width: 1200px; /* Or whatever */
}
```

If you need a fixed ratio:

```
.container::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 56.25%; /* 56.25% of the parent width this is, ratio 16x9 */
}
```

`min-width` can still be applied if needed. There's an [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) CSS property that can be used instead of that pseudo-element hack, but it is supported only in relatively fresh browser versions; still might be used if you don't plan supporting a little outdated browsers.

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to implement it to see how it works, this will keep the truffle-tin container the right width/height/x/y/ AND the buttons (truffle buttons) at the right positions within that container?

As well as responsive? Specifically, those <a> inline styles?

Comment: The `a`'s inline styles are here to let application dynamicly set them. If their positions are static for application life time, they may be harcoded into static CSS. The key idea is to keep `.container` exactly the same size as the image; in pretty the same situation i've put that image as `<img>` with `max-width: 100%` and `min-width: 480px /*or smthn*/` instead of background to let it keep actual `.container` aspect ratio for the `.container`, so i don't need the pseudo-element hack or `aspect-ratio` property.

Comment: I noticed the container had a height/width of 0, so only the pink button was showing. I set the container to height/width 100%, but the pink button is not maintaining a steady position over the image...

How should I write the container height/width?

Comment: Also, because the image is not filling up the screen, there's a large white space beneath the image. I need it to be the full size of the viewport (if 100% height, the width can be larger than the viewport, but never smaller).

And also, the pink button's width and height are fixed, when I would like them to match the dimensions of the truffle tin