# Creating responsive 'Image Map' for elements to match elements of background image (JS/CSS) (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, responsive

I'm trying to create a map that responsively aligns hyperlinks over an (always) full-screen background image.

I've tried SVG's, but that didn't work [for this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040631/svg-foreignobject-and-absolute-positioning).

So now I'm trying to use absolute positioning, so that the x/y AND height/width of the container (and therefore the little 'truffle' buttons) match the respective parts on the background image.

Below is the image, with the 'truffle box' that needs to align above the entire truffle tin (upper screen included)

[image]

Instead, what I've got is this (you can see, the viewport might be changing, but since the image isn't yet decreasing in size, neither should the 'truffle box' element):
[image]

Below is the code I'm using for the TruffleTin, to make it responsively maintain the x/y position, but I have nothing for it's height/width.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  TruffleTinContainer,
  TruffleTinOutside,
} from '../truffle-tin/styledTruffleTin';

export default function TruffleTin({ backgroundRef }) {
  const truffleTinRef = useRef();
  const initialPos = { x: 150, y: 150 };
  const padding = 25;
  let truffleBoxWidth = 0;
  let truffleBoxHeight = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    truffleBoxWidth = truffleTinRef.current.offsetWidth;
    truffleBoxHeight = truffleTinRef.current.offsetHeight;
    resize();
  }, []);

  function resize() {
    let backgroundDivRect = backgroundRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    truffleTinRef.current.style.left =
      (initialPos.x / truffleBoxWidth) * backgroundDivRect.width -
      padding +
      'px';
    truffleTinRef.current.style.top =
      (initialPos.y / truffleBoxHeight) * backgroundDivRect.height -
      padding +
      'px';
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
  });

  return (
    <TruffleTinContainer ref={truffleTinRef}>
      I'm the truffle tin
    </TruffleTinContainer>
  );
}
```

And here is what the image is, it's a div with a background image:

```
export const BackgroundLightsOn = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  background: url(${BgLightsOn});
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked at countless 'suggestions' for this, but nothing has worked thus far. I'm kind of under the gun here, so the most straightforward and effective answer would be the best! Thanks very much.

Comment: If the size of the background image doesn't change size until a certain breakpoint, than the width of the hyperlink should be constant until that breakpoint.  So the first thing I would do is find at what screen resolution the size of the background image changes and add separate logic depending if its inside or outside that breakpoint

Comment: that breakpoint will be 1600px, but i find, if i decrease the viewport width and height together, yes the truffle div more or less scales down appropriately. However, if I decrease just the width (so the viewport is now like 1000x1400), the truffle div becomes too narrow, therefore setting a percentage width wouldn't work in this case